# Can I connect HP Ultrium 1760 drive to LSI Logic SAS 3041E controller using the cable on the picture

Tags: sas, cable, controller, tapedrive, lto

I want to connect [HP StorageWorks LTO-4 Ultrium 1760](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=emr_na-c01386389) tape drive to [LSI SAS 3041E](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01511148) controller using the cable on the photo. The cable is advertised as [0.7M Mini SFF-8482 to SAS 29P SATA](https://www.ebay.com/itm/0-7M-Mini-SFF-8482-to-SAS-29P-SATA-Adapter-Hard-Drive-Splitter-Data-Cable-Latest/324307206620?hash=item4b823741dc:g:43UAAOSwLzFfbJJD) . Or an adapter like this (second picture): [SAS To Sata 22pin Adapter Cable SFF-8482 Conversion](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Main-Board-SATA-Adapter-SAS-To-Sata-22pin-Adapter-Cable-SFF-8482-Conversion/143581751342?hash=item216e23a82e:g:qc8AAOSwuQFel9AG)

- The device back is on photo No 3.
- The controller photo is No 4

**Update:** The device works with the blue cable from the first photo.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - actually both variants would do. SFF-8482 is the standard internal SAS device interface.

I'd prefer the adapter cable since it doesn't introduce additional connections. Watch out for the power connector, so you can connect it to your PSU. The once-ubiquitous Molex plug is getting rare these days.

Of course, the SAS-SATA adapter requires using a standard SATA cable.

Comment: I read that SFF-8482 is made to be compatible with SATA. Can't I just use SATA cable directly to the device? and sata power connector.

Comment: SFF-8482 cables and backplanes fit SATA drives but not the other way around. You can't fit a SATA cable since the data and power sections are joined together on a drive (the 2nd data lane is located on the joint).

Comment: I want to connect sas controller to sas drive. I found two types of SFF8482 cables  - one with one SATA connector to the controller(the ones on the picture) and one with two SATA connectors (2 lanes?). In the device description I see "Interface type: 3Gb/s SAS" which is the speed one one SAS-1 lane (same speed as SATA-2). So if the device is not using the second lane  (max transfer speed of the device is 80MB/s) maybe if the cables physically fit it'll work

Comment: Never mind. they won't fit physically. I had a second look at the connector...